# Windows 10 and Ubuntu not bootable

Tags: boot, windows

I was dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 10.
I had Ubuntu 17.04
I wanted tot delete Ubuntu (sorry Ubuntu!) and i red that 
you can delete Ubuntu via os-uninstaller but you needed
a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu on it. I have that and i did that.  On the stick there was no "try Ubuntu" option.
So i tried install Ubuntu. But i saw that that was the wrong option and quitted. Now Both os wont boot.
Sorry for bad english. Autocorrect is killing me.

Comment: You may now have to run Windows fixes. But if Windows 10 is UEFI, you have to delete /EFI/ubuntu folder and UEFI entries saved in its NVRAM. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

It should detect the systems installed and rewrite the grub loader correctly.